# Git: Says master is up to date, but when deleting branch it says it isnt'

Tags: git, version-control, github

I created a new branch for my 1.0.2 fixes. Once I was finished I wanted to merge them back into my master, so I used:

```
git merge 'v1.0.2'
```

But, it tells me that it is 'Already up-to-date`, which is strange. I say, ok, that is fine, so I try to delete the branch:

```
git branch -d 'v1.0.2'
```

But now it tells me `error: The branch 'v1.0.2' is not fully merged.`.

Why are my changes not being merged in the first place? Do I need to somehow force them to be merged?

**EDIT:**

Output of `git log --all --oneline --graph --decorate`

```
* a783018 (HEAD, origin/master, master) Updated with 1.0.2 changes
* c208285 Updates
| * 655b0ea (v1.0.2) Submitted 1.0.2 to apple for review
| * 0d4f33d Updates
|/  
| * 02f7155 (origin/v1.1, v1.1) Additional fixes
| * 5a68697 Renaming classes and .m .h files with three letter prefixes to comply with Apple requirements
| * c90a76d Added pin pad as an option
| * 3dc6ceb Adding new security methods to lock app if the user chooses
| * 3bf1c88 Updates
|/  
* 71af916 Bug fixes
* 523672f (tag: v1.0.2) Final fixes before release
* 0269dab Bug fixes and added new methods to specifically layout details screens
* e1e7c08 Bug fixes
* 071c9cc (tag: v1.0.1) Last changes before 1.0.1 submission
* 8d56576 Bug fixes
* 9e86414 Major file restructure for easier git viewing and structure
* 4f14c9e Updated a few methods to no longer use the Utility object
* 1be42ea Moved some properties to the ZSSingleton rather than the Squiz Matrix singleton
* 1450e7d Updated a few code snippets
* 27c3ebb Updated methods for Metadata
* baf8a6c (tag: v1.0) Final fixes, submitted to apple
* d5ffb6c Addtional fixes
* aa7d123 Removed unused files
* a472a1d Removal of old Matrix library. Removal of ASIHTTPRequest!
* b533ac3 Added new attribute types
* 76c29ef Adding UIDatePicker for creating of Calendar assets
* 1fb09dc Added some fixes for ipad
* 0f93c82 Cleaning up of code, adding comments
* 27c7984 Cleaning up of code, adding comments
* d0d29bb Added ignore file
* 7911483 A file was deleted
* fdba63c First add of all files
```

Comment: maybe commit it and see what happens

Comment: Tried committing and it was fine. No warning. Still confused though why deleting the branch tells me it is not fully merged.

Comment: why are you using the quotes?

Comment: I have no idea. Does it matter? I guess I was thinking of it as a string...

Answer (score 2):

You need to be on the other branch to merge them. so

```
git checkout master
git merge v1.0.2
git branch -d v1.0.2
```

It seems your merge failed. It is not fine that it tells you it's already up to date. Try adding `--allow-empty` to the merge just to test this out. Make sure you are on master when you issue the merge command.

Comment: I was on the master. Still says things are up to date. Then when deleting says `error: The branch 'v1.0.2' is not fully merged.`

Comment: to see what's happening (please post the output of this here) do `git log --all --oneline --graph --decorate`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
git checkout master
git merge refs/heads/v1.0.2
```

You apparently have both a branch and a tag with the name `v1.0.2`, and it seems that `git merge v1.0.2` prefers to guess that you want to merge with the tag, not the branch. The above syntax makes it explicit that you want to merge the branch instead.

Comment: I think that was the issue. Now it says `error: 'merge' is not possible because you have unmerged files.`

Comment: That sounds like you have a merge already in progress. If so, and you don't want to keep whatever has been done so far, `git merge --abort` should clean up the failed merge. Posting your `git status` may help identify other issues...

Comment: Ah, ok, so it looks like it is hanging on a binary file. I did `git merge --abort` and then tried the merge again and it tells me `warning: Cannot merge binary files: SquizMatrixiOS.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/webmaster.xcuserdatad/UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate (HEAD vs. refs/heads/v1.0.2)`. Is there a good way to resolve this? Sorry, new to merging...

Comment: Probably the best would be to do `git checkout --ours -- <file>`, then `git add <file>` and `git commit` to tell it your (`master`) version of the file (use `--theirs` instead to get the copy from `v1.0.2`). Then seriously consider whether you really need to track that file...

Comment: This sounds like a great idea, but it seems to not work. `Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit. Nothing to commit`. Arg. Not sure what to do. I would love to not track this file...

Comment: In that case it sounds like the merge was successful, but maybe didn't touch the one file - check your `git log --pretty=oneline --graph` again (or `gitk`). To stop tracking that file `git rm --cached <file> ; git commit` (may need to do it on several branches for a complete solution, otherwise it might show up again later).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22862/discussion-between-nic-hubbard-and-twalberg)